# Что такое "среда С++"?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Что такое среда С++? И вообще, как это можно описать? Я так-то понимаю, но вот как это в одном или нескольких предложениях выразить — не знаю.

Comment: "Он вырос в среде С++ программистов." Приведите пример контекста.

Answer (score 5):

Это программа в которую включен компилятор для языка C++. Она в своей сборке включает некоторые компоненты, которые облегчают и главное ускоряют разработку на языке программирования. Чаще всего это так называемые ***[IDE(Integrated Development Environment)](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8)***

В основном они включают:

- текстовый редактор
- компилятор и/или интерпретатор
- средства автоматизации сборки
- отладчик

Примеры для C++

- **[Microsoft Visual Studio](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio)**
- **[Dev-C++](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev-C%2B%2B)**

Answer (score 2):

Может иметься в виду C++ runtime -- библиотеки, которые всегда компилируются в вашу программу и занимаются внутренними обеспечивающими вещами, типа управления памятью (new/delete), обслуживанием исключений, реализацией RTTI, поддержкой работы контейнеров STL, многопоточности openmp и других фич С++, для реализации которых требуется некоторый программный код, **выполняемый** вместе с вашей программой.